# How to disable "Disassembly view" while debugging in CLion 2017.1.1

Tags: debugging, ide, clion

Recently JetBrains released a new version of CLion IDE with [the "Disassembly View" feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/whatsnew/#v2017-1-disasm).

Is there a way to disable this feature while line-by-line (F7) debugging C++ project in CLion 2017.1.1 ?

I can't found this option in Settings..

Comment: This is a valid request, which we hope to fix soon, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8978 debugger: Don't show disassembly when stepping unless using "Force Step Into"

Comment: I'd also like the opposite, to explicitly view disassembly even on fully symbolic-debug available code

Answer (score 1):

[From here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/03/clion-2017-1-eap-disassembly-view-catch-msvc-changes/)
saw that

> Now not, that’s why we plan to move it to the special stepping action – force step into (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8978), so that usual step into won’t fall into disassembly. However, as a workaround can’t you just do a step over?